# MySQL - is it possible to use aliases for column names in join comparison operators?

Tags: mysql

Example:

`SELECT * FROM T1 JOIN T2 on (T1.id = T2.id as aux)`

Where I'm trying to alias `T2.id as aux` - but that's throwing errors

...

so that the resulting fetched columns would have a column name of aux instead of just id for both o f them.

Comment: aliases are for column names and table names. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Why you need to keep an alias in that relation(between both tables) statement, you can't use that right. You can keep alias for **T1 & T2** and then select them using their alias, **select T1.id from T1 join T2 on (T1.id=T2.id)**

Comment: Aliased used so that the returned rows would not have the same column name

Comment: You can't use alias in this statement **(T1.id = T2.id as aux)** because you can't use this. But you can try something like this to avoid duplication of columns inside your select statement. **T1.id as t1id, T2.id as t2id**

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to alias columns like this. You could do it in a sub-query, but the proper way to achieve what you want is to explicitly list the projected columns, it's good style anyway. So:

```
SELECT T1.id, T2.id as aux, T1.col1, T2.col2 [,...] FROM T1 JOIN T2 on T1.id = T2.id
```